# .NET 6.0 web app very slow debugging in VS2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

So I am trying out .NET 6 for the first time. I created an empty web app based on .NET 6. It does NOT have docker support and I have changed nothing in the code.

When I run in IISExpress with the debugger (using F5) from VS2022, the site runs but each page load takes 2 seconds every time I go between "Home" and "Privacy". These are Razor pages in the sample but another app I was starting to build was also slow with controller actions. In the network tab, it is only the main request which is slow. Other js files are loaded quickly from the app and then cached.

Surely this can't be right?

Comment: Have you tried setting it up on Local IIS? It could just be that that buffer is the site compiling - if you set it to precompile it might speed things up.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan the pages load slowly every time (Just tried dotnet core 3.1 and similar problem), doesn't pre-compilation just remove the build that happens one-time when you first visit the page?

Comment: By the way, the same dotnet core 3.1 app is largely instant when running in VS2019 so either there is an unhelpful default, or some kind of bug but weirdly, I can't find many reports of slowness for VS2022.

Comment: Hmm... not sure then - I assume it's not just a case of you using all the RAM?

Comment: Sadly not. I am on a 32GB machine and the debug tools show the app using 61MB. I suspect it is related to the building of the views each time, since that makes the most sense.

Comment: Maybe you can create a trace to check where time is spent (e. g. `dotnet-trace`, dotTrace, etc.)

Comment: It takes like 5 minutes just to start debugging the template web site, seems like technology went backwards.

Comment: Which of the bots is answering? @ronan or @luke?

Comment: Although (in debug) there's a a lot of interference from the VS processes, with a 32GB machine (like you mentioned) should not be a problem unless you created it yourselves

Answer (score 4):

I have had this exact same issue for some time - consistent 2 second page load on a fresh template MVC project (.NET 6 and now .NET 7 as well) while lightning fast if published, run in the profiler or via Postman. The solution for me was to **disable 'CSS Hot Reload'** under **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **ASP.NET Core**.

Comment: Spent 20 minutes looking for answers already. Yours does the trick! Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying you run with IIS Express, this may not work for you. If you weren't actually running with IIS Express, but instead the default project executable it may.

Try the following:

- Close the project (possibly all Visual Studio instances)
- Open the project
- Switch it to run on IIS Express profile (dropdown beside the green run button)
- Run the project.

Closing Visual Studio seemed key to getting it out of the 2s reload.

My .NET 6 projects were having the same 2 page load times, even after repeat visits. If I freshly ran with my project profile instead and then the IIS Express one, the issue was there with both methods. If I freshly ran the IIS Express profile, then switch it to my project that now works fine. I'm just leaving it on IIS Express for now until I find a reason not to or it gets fixed. I have no idea on the underlying issue.

Answer (score -2):

I have encounter the same problem, and solve it with different ways:

- If you are in "In private" navigation, open another web borswer window without "In private".
- Otherwise, use another web browser

I know that's not correct the issue, but it's an helpful workaround.

Comment: Unless you can explain what the problem is, this is just a guess and it doesn't work for me. Other browsers and private/non-private all do the same.

Comment: It's a guess, but I'm able to reproduce the same issue with an ASP.NET Core MVC project with target .NET 6 in VS 2022, this is why I mentionned that's just a workaround.  The other problem is that I have not enough reputation for just post a comment...