# Visual Studio 2022 / ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : slow page loading

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded our ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project to .NET 6. This forces you to move from VS2019 to VS2022.

All was good until I noticed the load time for each view while debugging was consistently taking 2 seconds.

I initially concentrated on investigating the .NET 5 to .NET 6 upgrade but I found the same problem when comparing VS2019 to VS2022 with the .NET 5 version (pre-upgrade) - while debugging VS2019 loaded the views instantly and VS2022 took 2 seconds.

The published .NET 6 website runs very fast, so this is something to do with VS2022 default settings which slow the loading of controllers and views. I have gone through every post I could find to improve VS2022 performance with no luck.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I get the same 2 second load delay with "Start Without Debugging"

Comment: Please try to upgrade your VS2022 to latest version, then check the issue.

Comment: Checked for updates but already have the latest version - v17.2.6

Comment: are you using windows 11? if yes see this https://twitter.com/davkean/status/1539814648706662405?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1539814648706662405%7Ctwgr%5E985acbd6a01af9d0bd9968051d512fd1439e955d%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.neowin.net%2Fnews%2Fmicrosoft-confirms-visual-studio-net-broken-for-windows-11-insiders-fix-incoming%2F

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Please use the dotnet cli to start the application, I need the difference with the visual studio start.

Comment: Running the application using the dotnet cli is fast, no delays when navigating controllers

Comment: I suggest you go to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) to post for official help. If possible, use a gif tool to document the steps and results of reproduction.

Comment: This is only on debugging right? (so running from VS to start?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET 6.0 web app very slow debugging in VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74438562/8026469) (link to the solution for me)